# Мгновенная заливка файлов на FTP

Tags: ftp, php, сервер

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно настроить компьютер так: Есть FTP папка на сервере (ВебСайт с РНР) и хотелось бы, что бы она зеркально копировалась в локальную папку. И при изменении любого файла, на локальной или сервереной машине, файл автоматический загружался или выгружался. Тоесть подправил в локальном файле, нажал ctrl+s и файл уже на сервере - можно жать F5. Может быть есть стандартные схемы такого решения ? Большое спасибо :)

Comment: А прямо с ftp редактировать не подходит? Notepad++, например, позволяет редактировать прямо с ftp и ctrl-s работает...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если принципиально нужна отдельная программа для синхронизации, то как вариант - [WebSynchronizer](http://appossum.com/?page=techdetails&article=web-synchronizer)

Answer (score 0):

В любой IDE (NetBeans например) создаёте проект с удаленного сервера, в настройках как правило автоматом стоит выгрузка на сервер при сохранении. А зачем Вам загружать файл при изменении его на сервере я не могу понять. Логи чтоли загружать собрались? И вообще не проще ли на сервер заливать готовое рабочее решение?